# Using x:Name in WPF UserControl yields weird 'namespace does not exist' error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm adding a WPF UserControl to this gigantic application. Everything compiles and works fine, until I add `x:Name="MyCustomUserControlElement"` inside the `<UserControl>`. The namespace `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
 is also in the `<UserControl>`.

The error:

> Error 32  The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'CompanyName.Devision.Common.SoftwareLayout.Company.Devision' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)   MyCustomUserControl.xaml    Project:
>   CompanyName.Devision.Common

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Since this is XML, "x:Name" is an abbreviation of the "{namespace x stands for}:Name". In other words, x: is just an alias for a complete namespace-uri. You must have a "xmlns:x='some namespace" if you want to use the 'x' prefix.

Xmlns='namespace' is for the 'default namespace used for all elements without a prefix'

Comment: @MarvinSmit Sorry, I copied the wrong namespace. I updated the question. I did (and still do) have the `xmlns:x` defined in the `UserControl`.

Comment: The error reported is not about a missing xmlns declaration in XML. There seems to be a incorrect .Net namespace in use, or the assembly containing the namespace is not loaded with the app. Your error: ('CompanyName.Devision.Common.SoftwareLayout.Company.Devision' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: But that error only shows when I put `x:Name...` in the `UserControl`, if I do not put it there, all compiles and runs fine.

Comment: Its similar to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496353/cant-set-xname-root-on-usercontrol but I can't map the answer to my siuation to come to a solution. Because I do not have type with the same name as a namespace. But there is definitely some mix up in namespaces in msbuild.

Comment: Try turning on "Verbose mode" during compilation and read the raw log. Hopefully that will indicate WHY this is becoming a problem when you include the name attribute in the xaml.

Comment: Have you happened to figure this out yet?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: No I did not, I worked around the problem which didn't yield the proper solution I was aiming for.