# Binding to Dependency Properties within ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, xaml-binding

I have an ItemsControl with an inline ItemsSource as below (simplified):

```
<UserControl>
    <ItemsControl>         
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
               <x:Array Type="y:KeyData">
                  <y:KeyData Name="Name1"/>
                  <y:KeyData Name="Name2"/>
               </x:Array>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateDifferences:KeyData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

I now want to bind another value to each KeyData item. I've tried the below:

```
<UserControl>
    <ItemsControl>         
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
               <x:Array Type="y:KeyData">
                  <y:KeyData Name="Name1" Count="{Binding Count1}"/>
                  <y:KeyData Name="Name2" Count="{Binding Count2}"/>
               </x:Array>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateDifferences:KeyData}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

And set up a dependency property as below:

```
   internal class KeyData : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? Count
        {
            get { return (int?)GetValue(CountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("Count",
                                         typeof(int?),
                                         typeof(KeyData),
                                         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
    }
```

And pass in a Data Context:

```
<UserControlName DataContext="{Binding Container.APresenter}"/>
```

However, the bindings are failing to locate the source...

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or
>        FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>        BindingExpression:Path=Removed; DataItem=null; 
>        target element is 'KeyData' (HashCode=4638229); 
>        target property is 'Count' (type 'Nullable`1')

I thought this was the point of a Dependency Property - to handle cases like this? Is anyone able to point out the part I've misunderstood?

Comment: Which object do you expect to be the source of the `Count1` and `Count2` bindings? You would have to set the Source or RelativeSource or ElementName of the two bindings, as no DataContext is inherited into the Array.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean the source? Count1 would be an int on APresenter.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't put an APresenter instance into any DataContext, only into a design time DataContext. But even if you had done that, the DataContext won't be inherited be the elements in the Array.

Comment: @Clemens - I believe I'm setting the DataContext when creating the control? I'll update my question. So is there a way I can point the elements in the array to it?

Comment: There is already an answer to your question...

Comment: @Clemens: Thank you, I'm attempting to work on that one also, unfortunately, trying to name my UserControl seems to be preventing everything from compiling...

Comment: Ah, never mind chat, I just thought it might clear the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding does not know **who owns** `Count1` and `Count2`. Provide maybe an `ElementName` which refers to the object in question. Then *possibly* work off of its `DataContext` such as this binding:

```
="{Binding ElementName=PathBox, Path=DataContext.Count1}"
```

I find that naming Xaml elements (even the page) then pathing to that named object into its internals or if it is a control via its datacontext solves most binding issues.

### Update

Sometimes one has to [x:reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380(v=vs.110).aspx) to access named items. In that case depending on the object use x:name to name it then access it.

```
="{Binding Source={x:Reference PathBox} , Path=Count1}">
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, been trying to get something out of this. If I've set my datacontext as in the question, is it only accessible on the UserControl element? I don't seem to be able to give that a name, because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496353/cant-set-xname-root-on-usercontrol) (I think) - but equally, I don't seem to be able to locate it through RelativeSource either...

Comment: Hmm, no, nevermind, my data context must be set, as I'm accessing it for another textblock. But I don't seem to be able to access it from the Array items at all...

Comment: @Chris If you have named the UserControl, try just `Count1` instead of `DataContext.Count1` for in that case the DataContext is assumed.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be doing it either. I don't seem to be able to name my UserControl (namespace collision, perhaps?), but there's a stackpanel wrapping this ItemsControl, which I can see does have the data context from other bindings. But I don't seem to be able to get hold of that from within the Array for love nor money...

Comment: @CHris can you move your data array out of the control to the page's resource?

Comment: @Chris use `x:name` to name the object. Sometimes the Xaml Parser can't handle the 'Name' attribute and needs `x:name`.

Comment: Thanks @OmegaMan - I'll be able to get back to this soon and try these out! (I've tried x:Name to name the UserControl without success, but x:reference sounds promising!)

Comment: Finally managed to get things working through using a Pipe object, as per the second half of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8247368/1768779). I had issues with x:Reference due to cyclic dependencies, and then had the same issues even after extracting the array to resources. It's a horrible ugly way, but the only thing I could manage to get a result from in the end...I'll post a full answer of what I did tomorrow. Thanks for your help on this one, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

So, the eventual resolution.

Ignoring the obvious, that I'd missed a data context originally, after that, the challenge seemed to be in making the items in the array aware of the data context of the outside ItemsControl.

I tried referencing by both `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` - both of which it didn't seem possible to find. I tried to put an `x:Name` on the UserControl, and also reference using `x:Reference` as OmegaMan suggested in his answer.

None of these had the desired effect - the only working solution I could find was to use a ["Pipe Object"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247368/1768779), as detailed in the second half of this answer.

I have since refactored the array items into a separate user control, which in turn simplified the bindings.